# How to create a DIV onclick using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
  </head>
  <body>

      <h1>Etch-A-Sketch</h1>
      <p id="Grid-Size">Grid Size</p> 
      <form onsubmit="getTotalGridSize()"> <!--onsubmit has to be on the form tag not the submit input-->
        <input type="number" placeholder="size" min="1" max="100" id ="size" value="" oninput="getSizeValue()">
        <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="createTile()">
      </form>
      <p id="Colors">Choose Color</p> 

     <form id="color-options" >
       <input type="radio" name="choice" value="blue">
       <label for="default">Default</label>
       <input type="radio" name="choice" value="random"  >
       <label for="random">Random</label>
       <input type="radio" name="choice" value="white" >
       <label for="white">White</label>
       <input type="radio" name="choice" value="user" >
       <label for="color-picker">Color Picker</label>
       <input type="color" id="color-picker" value=""> 
     </form>
      <div id="Sketch">

        <div id="tile" onmouseover="updateHoverColor()">

        </div>
      </div>

      <script src="etch.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

```
//Dom Accessed Variables

    let tile = document.getElementById("tile")
    let sizeValue = null
    let gridSize= null 
    let containerDiv = document.getElementById("sketch")

//input functions 

    function getSizeValue() {
        sizeValue = document.getElementById('size').value //getting the inputs value
    }

    function getTotalGridSize() {
        gridSize = sizeValue * sizeValue

    }

    //Generates random RGB values
    function randomColor() {
        let red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
        let blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
        let green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
        //Returns string with style to be applied
        let random = `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`;
        tile.style.backgroundColor = random;

  }

  function updateHoverColor() {
    let colorChoice = document.getElementById("color-picker").value
    if(document.querySelector('#color-options > input:checked').value === "blue") {
        tile.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
    } else if (document.querySelector('#color-options > input:checked').value === "random") {
        randomColor()
    } else if (document.querySelector('#color-options > input:checked').value === "white") {
        tile.style.backgroundColor = "white"
    } else if (document.querySelector('#color-options > input:checked').value === "user") {
        tile.style.backgroundColor = colorChoice;
    }
  }

  function createTile() {
      let baby = document.createElement("div");
      baby.style.height = "200px"
      baby.style.width = "100px"
      baby.style.backgroundColor = "black"
      document.body.appendChild(baby)

  }
```

What I'm trying to do is have another div be created inside its container div after the user clicks on the submit button. I created a function using JavaScript which does that and then attached it to `onclick` on that same button. I even followed the exact same syntax to create the function from W3schools to create and append and element but it doesn't seem to be working at all in my code, and I'm trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem with your application is that when you submit some form, information is sent and page refreshes, your div is probably being created but later deleted because of page reload.

The best option is to save certain condition inside LocalStorage and everytime after refresh If page meets special conditions divs will be shown. Here is the example:

```js
function saveInformation(func) {

    var funcs = [
      'size',
      'save'
    ] 
    
    if (func==funcs[0]) {
        sizeValue = document.getElementById('size').value;
}
    if (func==funcs[1]) {
         localStorage.setItem('saveCheck','true');
}
    return false;
}

function check() {
    var saveCheck = localStorage.getItem('saveCheck');
    if (saveCheck == 'true') {
      generateDIV();
    } 

}

function generateDIV() {
    let element = document.createElement("div");
    element.style.height = "200px";
    element.style.width = "100px";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
    check();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="/html/b.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
      <input type='number' placeholder='Number' id='size'>
      <input type='submit' onclick='saveInformation("size");saveInformation("save");'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I could not save to Local Storage from Stack Overflow Code snippet, so you will need to test this code from an editor

What I did is that I disabled submit button with 'return false' but we are still getting information from input values, just without reload and with the shown div.

So idea is to have an fucntion that saves information from input value and saves bool called 'saveCheck' into the local storage. If the given 'saveCheck' from the local storage is true we are going to call 'generateDIV()' and from there we will have that div loaded every time page refreshes.

This is an example with pure Javascript, but I suggest you start using JQuery if haven't already.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Im not too familiar with localStorage, what would the code look like?

Comment: Hi i tried to do this but it wouldn't work for me either. I ended just changing the input type into a button, and then use an onclick from there. I feel like thats less complicated but it gets the job done so far. But thanks for the suggestion! I'll definitely look into it if i ever stumble on the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button within the first form has an `onclick`, *but* the containing form also has an `onsubmit`. That's going to cause some inconsistent behavior with respect to what functions are firing and when. Stick with the form `onsubmit`. I also recommend not attaching the event listener with HTML, but to give the form an ID and then attach the event listener through the ID.

```
// HTML
<form id="totalGridSizeForm">

// JavaScript
const gridSizeForm = document.getElementById("totalGridSizeForm");
gridSizeForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Whatever logic you need goes here
});
```

Comment: I tried this code word for word and I put my createTile function inside of it but it still doesn't do anything. It seems to work when I try other logic like alert("Hello") or if i call another function. It seems to be a problem with my createTile function but I can't figure out why.